# Fading text smoothly

Tags: javascript, html

I have a little feature that displays random text on a web page. You will see it working in this http://jsfiddle.net/argilmour/qvxhakjv/

```
var names = ["Harrogate", "Skipton", "York", "Northallerton", "Keighley", "Leeds", "Bradford", "Huddersfield", "Wakefield", "Sheffield"]
var namestemp = []
var randomIntervalLowerVal = 1100;
var randomIntervalUpperVal = 1500;
var currentSlideDirection = "left";

var site = {

    init: function () {

        setTimeout(function () { site.displayAndSpliceArrayItem() }, site.getRandomNum(randomIntervalLowerVal, randomIntervalUpperVal));
    },
    getRandomNum: function (min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    },
    displayAndSpliceArrayItem: function()
    {

        $("#randomNumber h1").fadeOut("slow");
        setTimeout(function () {

            $("#randomNumber")[0].innerHTML = "";

            var randomNum = site.getRandomNum(0, names.length - 1);
            $("#randomNumber").append("<h1 style='display:none;'>" + names[randomNum] + "</h1>");
            $("#randomNumber h1").show("slide", { direction: currentSlideDirection }, 1000);
            namestemp.push(names[randomNum]);
            names.splice(randomNum, 1);

            if (currentSlideDirection == "left") currentSlideDirection = "up";
            else if (currentSlideDirection == "up") currentSlideDirection = "right";
            else if (currentSlideDirection == "right") currentSlideDirection = "down";
            else currentSlideDirection = "left";

            if (names.length == 0) {
                names = namestemp;
                namestemp = [];
            }

            site.displayAndSpliceArrayItem();

        }, site.getRandomNum(randomIntervalLowerVal, randomIntervalUpperVal));
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    site.init();
});
```

Everything works fine except that just before the text fades out it seems to just jump up slightly. I am trying to get this so the text comes in, displays and then smoothly disappears.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry Mark - thank you for this - I didn't realise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like it is a positioning problem, add that line up to fadeOut line

```
$("#randomNumber").css('position', 'absolute');

$("#randomNumber h1").fadeOut("slow");
```

Comment: great it worked! if you can approve, the others can see it is working! Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
  h1 {
         text-align: center;
         position: absolute; /* added code*/
         font-size:1000%
    }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qvxhakjv/1/)